# Calculating polygon area in ArcGIS Engine

Tags: c#, arcgis-engine, area

I am new to using ArcGIS Engine 9.3. I would like to create an application to calculate the selected polygon in combobox such that the user click to a button and polygon area saved in dbf .

How can I write the code with c# in ArcGIS Engine?

Answer (score 1):

The [ArcGIS SDK 10 for C# help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html) has sample applications. You might want to check it out.